# Fscanf not reading floats from file properly into linked list

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf

So basically, using C, I'm trying to read information from a file into a linked list and I had this working when only the price was a float and size was a string but I need to read the size also as float.
I'm reading the file like this

```
fscanf(file,"%[^-]-%f[^:]:%f\n", pLog->name, &pLog->size, &pLog->price);
```

and the file's structure is like this

```
bottle-0.33:0.10
bottle-0.50:0.20
bottle-1.50:0.40
```

Now when I try to check the results with

```
printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n", pLog->name, pLog->size, pLog->price);
```

It prints everything like this

```
bottle 0.33 8290796282473829.00
:0.10 
bottle 0.50 2572489705689592000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00
:0.20
bottle 1.50 0.00
:0.40
```

Anybody have a clue what's going wrong?

Comment: `%f[^:]:%f` --> `%f:%f`

Comment: Hahaha boy do I feel stupid. Yes, you wouldn't need [^:] when not reading strings. Thanks, your a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code used wrong format  [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769653/fscanf-not-reading-floats-from-file-properly-into-linked-list/42771798#comment72654957_42769653)

```
// bottle-0.33:0.10
fscanf(file,"%[^-]-%f[^:]:%f\n", pLog->name, &pLog->size, &pLog->price);
```

`"%[^-]"` matches `"bottle"` and saves text in `pLog->name`.
`"-"` matches `"-"` and scanning continues.
`"%f"` matches `"0.33"` and saves the value 0.33 in `pLog->size`.
`"["` does not matches `":"`, so scanning stops, function returns a 2.
Remaining format `"^:]:%f\n"` is not relevant.

Use correct format, width limit and check result.

```
// assume sizeof pLog->name is 10
if (fscanf(file,"%9[^-]-%f:%f\n", pLog->name, &pLog->size, &pLog->price) == 3) 
  Success();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making a mistake there by passing the pointers to the `printf()` call, too.

```
  printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n", pLog->name, &pLog->size, &pLog->price);
```

should be

```
 printf("%s %.2f %.2f\n", pLog->name, pLog->size, pLog->price);
                                     ^^^         ^^^
```

FWIW, supplying mismatched argument to the format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, to match an input like `"bottle-0.33:0.10"`, a format specifier like `"%[^-]-%f:%f"` would also suffice.

That said, it's always required to check the return value of `scanf()` and family calls so as to verify the success. Otherwise, you'll probably end up using some uninitialized value, which may again lead to UB.

Comment: Sorry that was a writing mistake on my part. It is correct in the code. I was going to edit it but seems you were too fast.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check the return value of `fscanf`. Otherwise it would be quite obvious what has happened.

> Always check the return value of functions you call.

Comment: It returns 2 meaning it only managed to match 2 values which is obvious. What I wonder is why.

Comment: From your code it was not obvious that you knew `fscanf` would return 2. Otherwise you should have noted that in the question and not printed all 3 variables, which led to undefined behavior.